# Getting an error "Object variable not set" using VB

Tags: vba, split, vb6

I'm trying to write a program, which will delete every first letter of the words in MsgBox. Here is my code:

```
Sub Test 
dim k as String
dim f as String
dim bd as String
k = inputbox("input text")
f = "inputed text:" & chr(9) & k & chr(13)

bd = bd + Split(mid(k,1,1))

for i = 2 to len(k)
if mid(k,i-1,1) = "" then bd = bd + Ucase(mid(k,i,1)) else bd = bd + mid(k,i,1)
next i

f = f & "result of work:" & chr(9) & bd
MsgBox f

End Sub
```

I'm getting error here: `bd = bd + Split(mid(k,1,1))`

Comment: `Split` returns an array, not something you can add to the end of a `String`

Comment: Are you sure about the error? The problem braX mentioned (what is your idea of using split on a single character anyhow?)  throws a Type mismatch error. There are no objects involved in your code, so I don't see where your mentioned error message should come from. Btw: Use `&` for string concatenation, not `+`

Comment: Please, edit your question and show us an example of what you try doing. Firstly, the string you enter in `InputBox` and secondly how you like to look like after code processing. I cannot understand what you try doing...

Comment: Your question does not say what error you are getting

Comment: Based on the statement in the loop, I suspect that the `Split` function call should instead be a call to `Ucase`. The intent of this code does not appear to be deleting the first character of each word, but instead is capitalizing the first character of each word.

Comment: Also - the current `if mid(k,i-1,1) = "" then` is comparing the previous character to an empty string, that will always evaluate to False.  To capitalize the words the comparison should be to a space, eg `if mid(k,i-1,1) = " " then`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want removing of first letter of any wards in a string, please test the next code:

```
Sub deleteFirstWdLett()
 Dim x As String, i As Long, arr
 x = "My dog has three houses" 'consider it the InputBox string
 arr = Split(x)
 For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
    arr(i) = Mid(arr(i), 2)
 Next
 Debug.Print Join(arr, " ")
End Sub
```

What to happen if the word consists in only a letter? Should it be removed, resulting an extra empty space (as it happens above)? Should the code skip such cases? I cannot understand the reason of doing that, so I cannot imagine what you really need, from this point of view...